# diff between Privileges and acces level in MSCRM Dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In the Security in the MSCRM , there are different security implement in MSCRM, could anyboday define,what is diff between Privileges and acces level in MSCRM Dynamics 2011 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Privilege** is a permission to perform an action on a specific entity type in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Privilege is MS CRM 2011 we are providing the privilege Read, Write, Delete, Assign, Share, Append and append to.

**Access level** is provides accessibility in particular Entity in Microsoft CRM includes four distinct access levels presented in order in MS CRM User Level, Organization level and Business Unit etc.

Comment: Privileges aren't necessarily specific to an entity type.  There are multiple miscellaneous privileges.  (Publish Customizations, Go Offline, Act on Behalf of Another User)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good start: [how-to-interpret-accessrights-numbers](http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-interpret-accessrights-numbers.html).

Basically there are lots of different privileges. Certain tasks can require multiple privileges.  Some privileges also involve access levels that control a users rights to that privilege depending on the ownership of the entity in which they are acting upon.

### Example:

So you can grant a user the Read privilege on the Contact entity with an access level of Owner BU, and they will have access to read all Contacts that are in the same BU as they are.

Answer (score 0):

**Privileges**

Privileges are the most basic security unit in MSCRM, it define what actions a user can perform on each entity in the system.(Example Create, read update,delete,Append, Append To, Assign, Share)

**Access level**
The Access level indicates which records the user can perform that action upon for that entity like None , user , BU , Parent child BU , Organization

Comment: Privileges aren't necessarily specific to an entity type. There are multiple miscellaneous privileges. (Publish Customizations, Go Offline, Act on Behalf of Another User)

Comment: @daryl this link will make you clear http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg309366.aspx

Comment: I understand perfectly.  I just wanted to point out that some privileges aren't entity privileges.  They're classified as miscellaneous.